# Sync database with Android device and Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I want to create an App where the user can synchronize the data from the Android device with Google Drive. I store the user data in a SQLite Database on the device so my first thought was to upload the sql file. This is not a problem but I want to get access to this database file from a PHP Script on my WebServer (with the Google Drive JS SDK) so the user can change the data from any WebBrowser. At the moment I search for a Google Service with this propteries:

- Gratis / I don't want to pay for the storrage
- Store the user data on **their** Google Drive
- Connect easily to the data and read / change it

So witch Google Service do you think is the best for my plan? I do not know how many users from my app will use this. That's why I don't want to buy storrage because I can not predict how much it will cost in a month and here came the idea to store the user data on their own cloud storrage. Any ideas how to solve this problem? Or do you have any other ideas how to upload the data without to loose the benefits from a database?

Comment: What kind of data do you have? Are we talking just about one table or do you have a rich data model with let's say 100 tables?

Comment: No no not 100 tables but up to 10 tables is realistic.

Answer (score 1):

Just pay for the storage. It will make your life 10x easier. Is your app really planning on storing 10GB's of data per person? 100GB only cost $2.60 a month ($0.26 a user if they each used 10GB). Pricing found here: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/.

Regardless, you should be able to access their Google Drive account using PHP. Google Drive even gives you the ability to store files in a "special application specific" section of Google Drive which the user can only access via your applications (Android/iOS/Website).

See here to connect to Google Drive with PHP: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php